# Get id from grid in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using Php for back end development.

I have grid in Html which contains bunch of records.

Now what i want is , i want to get booking id on click(on click event has

java script function) on Booking

Number(As show in below image.) which has hyper link.

```
This is the java script function to get booking id  on click of booking Number

 $('.bu').on('click', function () {
                var Id = $(this).data("id");
                $.get( "mypage.php?id=" + Id );

                document.getElementById("idvalue").value = Id;
                 var inputdaata=document.getElementById("idvalue").value;

 **From above javascript already getting Booking id.

 Now i have to use that booking id in php.
 This is for grid in Html**

<td><a href="" name="abc"  
class ="bu"  data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#myModal1"  
 data-id="<?php echo $json1[$i] 
['bookingid']; ?>"><?php echo 
 $json1[$i]['bookingNumber'];?> 
</a></td>
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  
<script type="text/javascript">
     function gocedula(text) { 

   var form_data = {
    is_ajax: 1,
    cedula: text
   };

   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getCedula.php",
    data: form_data,
    success: function(response) {
     window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
   });
  
  }
 </script>
```

```html
<a onclick="gocedula('.$valor.')">Booking Number</a>
```

On the Other page use

```html
$_REQUEST["cedula"];
```

Comment: Will check that and let you know.

Comment: if you are trying to refresh some div, the code changes a little